# How do I enable device preview on Chrome via javascript api?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to be able to access the device preview mode from javascript. Is there an api for that?

There are some files under network that I suspect run this, but I'm looking for something that is more documented.

Comment: What is "device preview mode"?

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-M device mode cannot be invoked from js. There's no API to control devtools.

Comment: @DanielHerr [Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/)